# Header cant have a border

Tags: css, header

`border-width` doesn't work.

```
header {
    background-color: #58ACFA;
    text-align: center;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: black;
}
```

I tried to use `border-size` and it did not work.

How can I do it?

Comment: border: 5px solid  black;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
header {
    background-color: #58ACFA;
    text-align: center;
    border: 5px solid black;
}
```

Which is the same as

```
header {
    background-color: #58ACFA;
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
header {
    background-color: #58ACFA;
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: black;
}
```

you prob. forget a border-style. I added it for you. It can also be done on one line

```
border: 5px solid #000;
```